# Uniform Convergence on Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Show that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{^n}{n!}$$ converges uniformly on the disk D = {z : |z| < r} for every r > 0.
The series represents an analytic function S(z) on the entire complex plane. We know when z =x is real, $$S(x) = e^x$$

Anyone care to explain? I took the limit and it converges to 0 for all values of Z in the complex plane

Comment: "I took the limit and it converges to 0 for all values of Z in the complex place". I don't really understand what you mean with this.

Comment: I did the same and got 0, but I was asked to show uniform convergence based on the disk D = {z : |z| < r} for every r > 0. I don't know how to go about that

Comment: "took the limit". Sorry, limit to what?

Comment: How did you get zero? If you set $z=0$ you will get $S(0) = 1$. Convergence follows from the ratio tests.

Comment: limit of $$\frac{^n}{n!}$$

Comment: $S$ is the sum of terms. To show convergence you need to do more than show the individual terms go to zero.

Comment: Apply M-test and use the fact that $\sum \frac {r^{n}} {n!}$ converges.

Comment: That seemed to work. Thank you